# java-cloudant- Why find method does not return JSON instead of input stream?

Tags: java, json, couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to fetch the document from cloudant and after fetching it can not cast to Interface nested objects it is containing in the model class.

```
Service service = getDB().find(Service.class, service.get_id());
```

in my case the service class has multiple interfaces as member variables and I can not cast it while getting document from cloudant.

Is there a better way to fetch it? 
or can cloudant library provide method with return type as JSONString (the way they accept json as parameter?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSONObject in place of your Service class. Add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
   <artifactId>wink-json4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Import JSONObject in your class:

```
import org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONObject;
```

Get the document from the database as a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject service = getDB().find(JSONObject.class, service.get_id());
```

FYI, I believe JSONObject from Google Gson will also work:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Never thought this way! Thanks :)